# method and needed tests for assumption in analyzing a paired sample Likert measure?

Tags: t-test, paired-data, paired-comparisons

I am writing an exploratory paper considering an argument that a certain reaction that can arise in the viewing of art can serve as an empirical indicator that another particular cognitive process has occurred within their experience (in this case that one has changed some component of their own self-conception).

(for example: say that when people report that they "felt like sneezing" in an art encounter, we would also expect that they should have changed some component of their self image. Those who did not feel like sneezing should show no change.)

To measure this, we gave a pre-test with twenty 7-point bipolar adjectival scales (e.g., good...bad) assessing people's conception of self image, then had them view art, and then administered a second test with the same questions as well as a question assessing (Y/N) whether they felt like sneezing. The population size was 21 individuals taken from a museum population, with about 40% feeling like sneezing.

I am wondering what would be the best test to compare changes in self conception between the sneeze and no-sneeze populations. I originally did a paired sample t-test on both populations, and showed a significant change in certain measures for the sneezing group. However have been told that this method is not appropriate.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: "*have been told that this method is not appropriate*" - on what basis?

Comment: To clarify, I can see several potential things they might have said was a problem. I'm curious what they actually thought the problem was.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. To answer your question, and to give a little context. I submitted the paper with a paired sample t-test done independently for both populations (e.g., looking for sig. changes in pop. A and none in pop. B). They were separate because the original study was very exploratory and not set up to be a factorial design. Showed t test results and also P values and Cohen's d. However one reviewer wrote "this test is not appropriate." full stop.

Comment: continued from above: It seems to me that even given the issues with possible assumption violations in relation to Likert scales, a t test is still the common way to go in the social sciences. As I am trying to divine what exactly he/she was objecting to (one of my favorite joys of peer review), I wanted to know if I am missing something obvious. e.g., if you had this raw data what series of tests would you do to show sig. changes in one population and none in another?

Comment: Also, would a test like Wilcoxon be better?

Comment: '*However one reviewer wrote "this test is not appropriate." full stop*' -- What the heck are you supposed to do with that? The editor ought to have gotten them to clarify. However, you can't show "no change" at all. The absence of significance doesn't show equality. However, you can demonstrate that you have good power to pick up differences of some specific size and then show you didn't. While it's possible that the Wilcoxon is an issue, I suspect it's more likely to be a broader issue of the style of model used.

Comment: We can make all the guesses that we like, but without knowing what the reviewer actually intended, you might change ten things and they might say "nope, that wasn't it". You may be safer to ask for clarification. Meanwhile if I come up with suggestions about a model that better encompasses the design and the question of interest, I'll post an answer.